# 'Valuation a' data structure and 'eval' function

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I'm studying haskell and I don't know how to complete one exercise:

We can define a data structure for generalised expressions as
follows:

```
data Expr a = Lit a | EVar Var | Op (Ops a) [Expr a]
type Ops a = [a] -> a
type Var = Char
```

To evaluate an expression, we need to know all the values of its variables.
Define a new type or datatype Valuation a, associating variables with values
of the type a. Then write a function:

```
eval :: Valuation a -> Expr a -> a
```

that, for the given variable valuation and expression, evaluates (folds) the
expression to a single value.

Extra information (given by my professor with the exercise):

> Valuation could be any type,  associating Var (= Char) and 'a', example: >[(Var,a)] or Var -> a .
>
> eval function, after receiving a structure (of type: Valuation a) and an >expression (of type: Expr a), should simplify that expression to one "a" type >value.
>
> Expression (Expr Int) example: standard expression such as (x + 10) * y would >look like this: Op* [Op+ [EVar ‘x’, Lit 10], EVar ‘y’]. Is Valuation Int type >structure would associate EVar ‘x’ with 15 and EVar ‘y’ with 2, then the end >result should be 50.

My questions would be:

1) How should such data structure of Valuation a look like? I'm thinking about some kind of a map with keys and values, but I might be totally wrong.

2) For eval I was thinking about writing a function which would include all operators and their priorities, but overall this exercise looks a bit too difficult (in my mind) compared to other exercises we usually do - most of the time the hardest part is figuring out what the exercise wants and the solution itself takes up only about 5-15 lines of code; so, maybe my thinking for this exercise is off?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to add, as text, the statement of exercise (or at least as much of it is needed to make the question self-contained).

Comment: @duplode, thank you for your comment and sorry if my original post didn't contain the necessary information, I edited it, but if it's still missing something, please tell me. Thank you again and sorry, I'm kinda new to stack overflow.

Comment: This is quite a bit better now; let's see if it will get reopened. Meanwhile, a few hints: (1) "I'm thinking about some kind of a map with keys and values" -- That is one possibility; the `[(Var,a)]` type you mention in the "extra information" is a crude version of that idea. (2) "I was thinking about writing a function which would include all operators and their priorities" -- As far as your problem statement goes, there is no list of "all operators" for you to include, as any `[a] -> a` function wrapped in an `Op` will do. That might actually make things simpler for you.

Comment: @duplode, That "extra information" is what my professor added as bonus info (I should probably clarify this in the post as well) and I didn't quite understand the `[(Var,a)]` part; is it a list of tuples?

Comment: Yup, it is a (the type of) a list of tuples. It can be used as a key-value map as long as you don't mind the suboptimal performance or the fact that there is no guarantee that keys are unique. (For a proper dictionary type, see, for instance, [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Map.html).)

Comment: @Grimp, as for the list of operators with priorities, this is unnecessary -- once you have an `Expr`, the expression has already been parsed. To evaluate an `Op` expression, you just need to `eval` each of the arguments and then pass them to the `[a] -> a` function you have.

Comment: @duplode, okay, thanks, that actually helped me quite a bit. Btw, how can I upvote comments?

Comment: @Grimp Comments are upvoted through an arrow to the left of the comment that shows up on hover. I believe you need 15 reputation to be able do that, though.

Comment: @luqui, the thing is, I don't have such function yet (I think you're referring this part: `type Ops a = [a] -> a`?); correct me if I'm wrong, but this function should take a list of `Op` expressions as one parameter and return one `Op` expression as a result?

Comment: @duplode, the reputation restriction would explain it, I don't have enough rep yet because I'm new; wanted to upvote your comment because it helped, will do that later tho.

Comment: You do actually have that function. It's the first parameter of the `Op` constructor.  That is, when you pattern match `eval valu (Op f es) = ...`, then `f` is your function.  The op constructor says it has type `Ops a`, which is `[a] -> a`, which is what you need.  I'm trying to be as explicit as I can here, there are probably a few new concepts for you in this exercise

Comment: @luqui, yeah, there are a few new concepts for me here, thank you for your help, I'll try to look into all this on my own, but if you could provide a link where I could read more about everything you mentioned in your comments, that would help me even more. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Grimp, everybody usually suggests LYAH, here's the chapter on [data types](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#algebraic-data-types) which seems about where you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consolidate the comments into an answer:

> 1) How should such data structure of Valuation a look like? I'm thinking about some kind of a map with keys and values, but I might be totally wrong.

You are indeed looking for something that associates `Var` keys with `a` values. A `[(Var, a)]` list of pairs is one way of achieving that. You can then work with such a list using functions like [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup):

> ```
> lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
> ```
>
> `lookup key assocs` looks up a key in an association list.

Alternatively, you might want to consider using a proper map type, such as  [`Map` from *containers*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.8.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html).

> 2) For eval I was thinking about writing a function which would include all operators and their priorities [...]

Given your problem statement, there is no list of "all operators" from you to include. A second look at the `Expr` definition...

```
data Expr a = Lit a | EVar Var | Op (Ops a) [Expr a]
type Ops a = [a] -> a
```

... shows that an `Op` expression already encapsulates the operation to be done, in the form of the `[a] -> a` function in is its first field. Your task, then, boils down to converting the `[Expr a]` in the second field into an `[a]`, handling  each of the three types of `Expr` appropriately, and then apply the `[a] -> a` function to the resulting `[a]` list.